# C# Replace wildcard

Tags: .net, regex, string, c#-3.0

I am making an application to change the the resolution of that game, to the requested resolution.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Documents and Settings\ARTech\Bureaublad\PersistentSymbols.ini");//Reads the file.
string content = reader.ReadToEnd();//Puts the content of the file, into a variable.
reader.Close();
string replace = "persistent extern INDEX m_pixScreenWidth=(INDEX)" + txtWidth.Text + ";";
content = content.Replace("persistent extern INDEX m_pixScreenWidth=(INDEX)1920;", replace);//Replaces the ScreenWidth of the game to the requested number.
replace = "persistent extern INDEX m_pixScreenHeight=(INDEX)" + txtHeight.Text + ";";
content = content.Replace("persistent extern INDEX m_pixScreenHeight=(INDEX)1200;", replace);//Replaces the ScreenHeight of the game to the requested number.

StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Documents and Settings\ARTech\Bureaublad\PersistentSymbols.ini");
writer.Write(content);//Saves the changes.
writer.Close();
```

The problem is, that the resolution is not always 1920 x 1200, so I need some kind of wildcard which accepts everything between `persistent extern INDEX m_pixScreenWidth=(INDEX)` and `;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into an INI reader/writer such as this project: [An INI file handling class using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/cs_ini.aspx). Then you could grab the desired key and set the value appropriately.

Otherwise, you could write a regex such as this one:

```
string input = @"persistent extern INDEX m_pixScreenWidth=(INDEX)1920;
...
persistent extern INDEX m_pixScreenHeight=(INDEX)1200;";
string width = "800";
string height = "600";

string pattern = @"(persistent extern INDEX m_pixScreen(?<Type>Width|Height)=\(INDEX\))\d+;";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern,
                    m => m.Groups[1].Value
                         + (m.Groups["Type"].Value == "Width" ? width : height)
                         + ";");

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Pattern breakdown:

- `(persistent extern INDEX m_pixScreen(?<Type>Width|Height)=\(INDEX\))`: Your expected text, including height/width and the index text, is placed in a capture group by the opening and closing parentheses. We will refer to this later.
- `(?<Type>Width|Height)`: a named capture group that alternates between width and height to capture both. This way one pattern can handle both types of text.
- `\(INDEX\)`: parentheses must be escaped to be matched literally since they hold special meaning in regex if unescaped (used for grouping as done above).
- `\d+`: `\d` matches a digit `[0-9]`. The `+` makes it match at least one number (1 or more digits).
- `;`: this matches the trailing semicolon

A lambda is used with the `MatchEvaluator` overload of the `Replace` method. Essentially you are building the string back up. `Groups[1]` refers to the first group of text captured (see the first point above in the pattern breakdown). Next we check the named group of `Type` and check whether we are dealing with a width or a height. We substitute the new value appropriately. Finally we add that semicolon at the end to get the final replacement result.

Answer (score 4):

You should take a look to regexp :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx

Comment: Shortly you need to get something like m_pixScreenHeight=[0-9]* as a regexp